# node_modules slow down the VS 2017 IDE

Tags: angular, node-modules, visual-studio-2017

I am working on an angular 2 project, and it is created by angular/CLI. After I opened my project by 'open -> folders,' the CPU usage been boosted to over 50% and everything becomes very slow. I tested it that the slowdown issue caused by 'node_moduls'. After I removed this folder, the IDE will back to normal.

However, in the project, I still need the 'node_moduls' folder, because I got error message everywhere if I removed the 'node_moduls' folder! Even an import from the angular core!

`import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';)`

Is any way to fix this problem?

As I can see, VS 2017 keep scanning my folders and files, and this process has been taken for 3 hours. Now the IDE still takes 30% usage of the CPU usage. I think it needs to port the VS code's folders management idea to VS 2017.
[image]

And I have checked the "exclude" option that should show on the right-click menu. However, it does not have any option for excluding the folder.

[image]

update: It has been a night, (I kept the VS2017 open) the VS still taking 30-40% CPU usage, and the scanning data still on 45% same with the first image.

Comment: Why don't you just exclude `node_modules` from your solution / project?

Comment: @pixelbits because it does not have an option for excluding `node_modules`.......

Comment: I think this problem caused by the VS 2017 function mapping system. The IDE will scan each file and store them in an SQLite file that locates in the .vs folder (this is a hidden folder). The size of SQLite file would over 50MB.

Comment: My project won't build with the node_modules folder included in the project. I have the exclude option there but selecting actually crashes VS 2017. Even having it included in the first place caused VS 2017 to hang. I had to manually repair the solution file. VS 2017 typescript and angular support is still beta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using

> File -> Open -> Folder

use

> File -> Open -> Web Site...

UPDATE:

or (thanks wodzu)

> Solution > Add > Existing Website

Navigate to the location on your hard drive where the project lives and select its directory.

Since it is after all a web site that should work fine and it doesn't perform the scan.

I had the same issue but didn't want to modify the tsconfig.json file since that configuration is used by the angular cli tool which we use to compile the app.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this way. It works for me now thank you

Comment: or: solution > add > existing web site

Answer (score 1):

Don't include `node_modules` in your VS project because it takes forever to load.

In your `tsconfig.json` file, you need to exclude the `node_modules` folder from being compiled:

```
"compilerOptions": 
    ...
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make angular2 node_modules work in Visual Studio I had to add **"skipLibCheck": true** to the *tsconfig.json* file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...
    "skipLibCheck": true
   }
}
```

This will prevent the node_modules from being built with typescript.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this one, but it is not working... I think it is a problem of the VS 2017. I can see the VS2017 is seeking to scan all the files and store the path and functions in an SQLite file. I think it is the reason why the IDE is getting slow, which is the VS code does not to do.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new Visual Studio project and add all these files excluding node_modules folder to that project by drag and drop to solution node in Solution Explorer. The node_modules folder should be there in your project's directory but not included in your VS project.

Comment: The easy way would be to right-click the `node_modules` directory and choose *Exclude From Project*.

Comment: @Stijn If you open a project as a folder that right click option does not exist.